# undefined method `questions' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailboxer

I am getting a NoMethodError `` undefined method `questions' for nil:NilClass ``. It's pointing to the create action on the line `@question = @conversation.questions.build(params[:question])`

Questions controller:

```
  respond_to :js, :html

   def index
      @questions = Question.all
      respond_with(@questions)
  end

  def show
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    @questions = Question.order("created_at DESC")
    respond_with(@questions)
  end

  def new
    @question = Question.new
    respond_with(@question)
  end

  def create
      @question = @conversation.questions.build(params[:question])
      if @question.save
        @message = current_user.messages.new(:subject => "You have a question from #{@question.sender_id}",
                               :notification_id => @question.sender_id,
                               :receiver_id => @question.recipient_id,
                               :body => @question.question)

        @question.message = @message
        @question.save
        redirect_to questions_path, notice: 'Your question was saved successfully. Thanks!'
      else
        render :new, alert: 'Sorry. There was a problem saving your question.'
      end
    end
  end
```

Conversations controller:

```
       helper_method :mailbox, :conversation
        before_filter :conversation, only: :show

     def index
        @conversations ||= current_user.mailbox.inbox.all
        end

      def reply
        current_user.reply_to_conversation(conversation, *message_params(:body, :subject))
        redirect_to conversation
      end

      def trash_folder
        @trash ||= current_user.mailbox.trash.all 
        end

      def trash
        conversation.move_to_trash(current_user)
        redirect_to :conversations
        end

      def untrash
        conversation.untrash(current_user)
        redirect_to :conversations
        end

        def empty_trash
          current_user.mailbox.trash.each do |conversation|    conversation.receipts_for(current_user).update_all(:deleted => true)
          end
         redirect_to :conversations
        end
      end

  private

  def mailbox
   @mailbox ||= current_user.mailbox
  end

  def conversation
   @conversation ||= mailbox.conversations.find(params[:id])
  end

  def conversation_params(*keys)
   fetch_params(:conversation, *keys)
  end

  def message_params(*keys)
   fetch_params(:message, *keys)
  end

  def fetch_params(key, *subkeys)
   params[key].instance_eval do
     case subkeys.size
     when 0 then self
     when 1 then self[subkeys.first]
     else subkeys.map{|k| self[k] }
     end
   end
  end
end
```

Messages controller:

```
 def index
      redirect_to conversations_path(:box => @box)
    end

  # GET /message/new
  def new
    @message = current_user.messages.new
  end

   # POST /message/create
  def create
    @recipient = User.find(params[:user])
    current_user.send_message(@recipient, params[:body], params[:subject])
    flash[:notice] = "Message has been sent!"
    redirect_to :conversations
  end
```

Questions model:

```
  attr_accessible :answer, :question, :sender_id, :recipient_id
  belongs_to :user

  belongs_to :sender,
    :class_name => 'User',
    :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
    belongs_to :recipient,
    :class_name => 'User',
    :foreign_key => 'recipient_id'

    belongs_to :message

end
```

User model:

```
 acts_as_messageable
  has_many :notifications
  has_many :questions, foreign_key: :recipient_id
  has_many :sent_questions, class_name: 'Question', foreign_key: :sender_id


    def mailboxer_email(object)
        if self.no_email
          email
        else
            nil
        end
    end
end
```

development log:

```
Started POST "/questions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-29 12:32:46 -0400
Processing by QuestionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"YWtv+TixScaYsXpJ6F47uBHkNvcruyHV7cyOtU6pWnQ=", "question"=>{"question"=>"This question should have an conversation id", "sender_id"=>"2", "recipient_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Add Question"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`auth_token` = 'Mqy5_1kyb4hAsrmB9Q0fug' LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `questions` (`created_at`, `question`, `recipient_id`, `sender_id`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2014-05-29 16:32:47', 'This question should have an conversation id', 1, 2, '2014-05-29 16:32:47')
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Message: notification_id, reciver_id
    app/controllers/questions_controller.rb:23:in `create'
    app/controllers/application_controller.rb:13:in `user_time_zone'
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `notifications` (`body`, `created_at`, `sender_id`, `sender_type`, `subject`, `type`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('This question should have an conversation id', '2014-05-29 16:32:47', 2, 'User', 'You have a question from 2', 'Message', '2014-05-29 16:32:47')
  SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE `questions` SET `message_id` = 164, `updated_at` = '2014-05-29 16:32:47' WHERE `questions`.`id` = 135
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/questions
Completed 302 Found in 308ms (ActiveRecord: 10.2ms)
```

This new code is preventing the question from being created in the Questions table. I made the changes to the code because I had the questions submitting to the database but it was not creating a `conversation_id` with the mailboxer gem inside the Notifications table. Below is the original code that created the question inside the Questions table, but had `NULL` for `conversation_id`.

```
def create
    @question = Question.new(params[:question])
    if @question.save
      @message = current_user.messages.new(:subject => "You have a question from #{@question.sender_id}",
                             :notification_id => @question.sender_id,
                             :reciver_id => @question.recipient_id,
                             :body => @question.question)

      @question.message = @message
      @question.save
      redirect_to questions_path, notice: 'Your question was saved successfully. Thanks!'
    else
      render :new, alert: 'Sorry. There was a problem saving your question.'
    end
  end
```

So I need help with fixing the undefined method and having the question submit to the database with a `conversation_id`. I need the `conversation_id` set so the Question can be sent to the recipients inbox (this is where the user answers their questions).

Comment: Do you have any `before action` callbacks in `QuestionsController`?

Comment: @Pavan None for the Questions controller. Only `before_action` is inside the conversations controller.

Comment: Is that your full code of `QuestionsController`?

Comment: @Pavan just added the entire code from the questions controller.

Comment: Please revert back the `QuestionsController` to its original state.I mean you added this line `@conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversation_id])` now which makes the error meaningless.

Comment: @ Pavan controller back to original state and question/user model has been added.

Comment: Do you have a `Conversation` model?

Comment: @Pavan There's no conversation model

Comment: Then how could you relate `Question` with a conversation? I guess you should have a `Conversation` model.

Comment: @Pavan conversation_id's are supposed to be created from `current_user.send_message`. Mailboxer doesn't depend on a model to generate the ids. So I'm not understanding how creating a conversation model would solve the issue. Take a look at the definition of the method from their wiki http://rubydoc.info/github/ging/mailboxer/Mailboxer/Models/Messageable#send_message-instance_method

Comment: Can you explain how the `conversation_ids` will create from `current_user.send_message`?

Comment: @Pavan the `send_message` is suppose to create the conversations. This is how it's setup in the messages controller `current_user.send_message(@recipient, params[:body], params[:subject])` From wiki `Sends a messages, starting a new conversation, with the messageable as originator.`

Comment: From this line `@recipient = User.find(params[:user])`,i guess `current_user.send_message` just sends a `message` which matches the respected `recipient_id` but not create a `conversation`.

Comment: I know nothing about `mailboxer gem`.I'm just trying to figure out how `consersation_ids` will create.So please don't disappoint with my questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `@conversation` variable is never set to anything, so it is nil. You need to initialize it to something, either by setting it to `Converation.new` or retrieving a conversation from the database (which appears to be what you want to do in this case).

Comment: Adding a `@conversation = Conversation.new` creates the same error message.

Comment: after running `@conversation = Conversation.new`, your `@conversation` object is still nil? Did you override that method in your model? If so, you can try to initialize fields in your `initialize` method instead (don't forget to call `super` at the beginning of the method.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. `conversation.new` was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `@conversation` that holds a `nil` value in your `create` action of your `QuestionsController`,because it not set to nothing. Try giving it like this

```
def create
    @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:id])
    @question = @conversation.questions.build(params[:question])
    if @question.save
      #scoping to the current user is the right thing to do here
      @message = current_user.messages.new(:subject => "You have a question from #{@question.sender_id}",
                             #Original code :sender_id
                             :notification_id => @question.sender_id,
                             #Original code :recipient_id
                             :receiver_id => @question.recipient_id,
                             :conversation_id => @cnversation.id
                             :body => @question.question)

      @question.message = @message
      @question.save
      redirect_to questions_path, notice: 'Your question was saved successfully. Thanks!'
    else
      render :new, alert: 'Sorry. There was a problem saving your question.'
    end
  end
```

Hope it helps!

**Update**

I believe you should have a `Conversation` model to relate the `Question` model.Create a `Conversation` model by generating this query

```
rails g model Conversation
```

Add a relation `has_many questions` to the `Conversation` model

```
Class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :questions

end
```

And also You should be adding a `belongs_to conversation` in your `Question` model.

Try updating your `Question` model

```
Class Question < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessible :answer, :question, :sender_id, :recipient_id

belongs_to :user

belongs_to :sender,:class_name => 'User',:foreign_key => 'sender_id'

belongs_to :recipient,:class_name => 'User',:foreign_key => 'recipient_id'

belongs_to :message

belongs_to :conversation

end
```

Comment: I tried that immediately after Zachary's post and it did not work. I just c&p yours in case I spelt something wrong and it provided the same result as last night. ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /questions
 `Couldn't find Conversation without an ID`. My understanding is `current_user.messages.new` should be creating the `conversation_id`, but it's not. So setting the conversation variable will not work since `Conversation.find(params[:id])` is trying to find something that doesn't exist. Mailboxer gem is getting the best of me lol.

Comment: @pwz2000 try giving it like this `@conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversaton_id])`

Comment: Same error unfortunately. The problem is `conversation_id` is not being generated from `current_user.messages.new`

Comment: Try giving it in the @message like this `:conversation_id =>@conversation.id`

Comment: Sorry for the delay, was still working on this issue. Your recommendation did not work. It points to `Couldn't find Conversation without an ID` with the line `@conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversation_id])`. If removed it goes back to the error `undefined method `questions' for nil:NilClass` for `    @question = @conversation.questions.build(params[:question])`. Perhaps I should move this code to the Messages controller?

Comment: Unfortunately this leaves `conversation_id` NULL. I added the development logs.

Comment: @pwz2000 Try my updated answer as it is with the controller code also.I added this line now `:conversation_id => @cnversation.id`.

Comment: For starters I have to remove the line `@conversation = Conversation.find(params[:id])` otherwise I get the error `Couldn't find Conversation without an ID`. If having just `@question = @conversation.questions.build(params[:question])` I then get a ``undefined method `questions' for nil:NilClass``. If I replace that line with `@question = Question.new(params[:question])` it will work and submit to the database. The new line added `conversation_id => @conversation.id` gives the error ``undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass``.

Comment: Just a side note for a reminder, I am working out of two tables: `Questions` and `Notifications` table.

Comment: @pwz2000 Now try giving `@conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversaton_id]) instead of  @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:id])`

Comment: Ok I replaced `@question = @conversation.questions.build(params[:question])` with `@question = Question.new(params[:question])` since that line was giving me a undefined method. I added `@conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversaton_id])` but that gives the same error `Couldn't find Conversation without an ID`. It's unable to find a `conversation_id` that was never created.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a `before_create` callback in your model:

```
#app/controllers/conversations_controller.rb
Class ConversationsController < ActiveRecord::Base
    def create
         @conversation = Conversation.new(conversation_params)
         @conversation.save
    end

    private

    def conversation_params
        params.require(:conversation).permit(:conversation, :params, questions: [])
    end
end


#app/models/conversation.rb
Class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_create :build_questions

    private
    def build_questions
         self.questions.build
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I tried your code but it doesn't fix the `conversation_id` from being NULL.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the error results from never setting the `@conversation` variable at all.

However, I believe no one who has answered so far realizes that `Conversation` is a model inside the `mailboxer` gem: `Mailboxer::Conversation`.  Conversation instances are available from the result of the `send_message` call.  You'd have to say:

```
receipt = send_message ....
conversation = receipt.conversation
# Now you can save the conversation of this message 
# in some useful place so it can be found later.
```

The other place conversations are available is in the `messageable`.  I gather that this is your `User` model and appears as `current_user`.

You can get all the conversations of the current user with

```
current_user.mailbox.conversations
```

You can perform some filtering by choosing a single message queue instead, for example:

```
current_user.mailbox.inbox
```

Of course you probably want to get the last conversation.  For this, you want

```
current_user.mailbox.conversations.last
```

So my wild guess is you might want

```
@conversation = current_user.mailbox.conversations.last
```

Another inconsistency in your code is that the basic `Mailboxer::Conversation` model created by the generator has no `questions` relation, yet you seem to be assuming there is one when you say

```
@conversation.questions
```

To relate conversations to questions, you will have to monkey patch with something like:

```
class Mailboxer::Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
end
```

in your own file `app/models/conversation.rb`.  Additionally, this makes sense only if there is a `belongs_to :conversation` and foreign key `conversation_id` in the `Question` model.  You don't have either.

In summary, two observations:

1. You'll need to spend some time learning how `mailboxer` works by studying its source code because the documentation is sparse.
2. There is at least the fatal inconsistency in your models described above.  Others are likely.  You'll have to fix these before you have any hope of success.  The way to do this is *test the models before moving on to the controllers*.  Success in Rails is all about getting the models exactly right.

Comment: I will continue studying the mailboxer source code to try and understand how `conversation_id` is generated. The initial undefined method problem has been solved as stated in original question. It was a two part question of fixing the undefined method and correcting `conversation_id` from being `NULL`. Thanks for taking the time to respond to my question.

Answer (score 0):

From the mailboxer documentation, I can see that any message has a `conversation_id`. You claim that the question's `conversation_id` is not set, so I think your question model also has a link to a conversation?

Yet I do not see that `belongs_to` in your question model?

So I see a few options:

- either you should access the conversation through the message, e.g. `question.message.conversation`
- either you want the `conversation_id` of the question to be the same as that of the message, do something like

  @message = current_user.messages.new(...) 
  @question.message = @message
  @question.conversation_id = @message.conversation_id

You do save the `@question` but not the `@message`? Is that the problem?

- either your `@message` is not created with a conversation, but maybe you should `send` it, like you do in your `MessagesController` :

  @message = current_user.send_message(....
  @question.update_attributes :message_id => @message.id

Hope this helps.